# load properties in mule munit

Tags: java, mule, munit

I have some placeholders in my flow. Values for these placeholders are specified in a properties file (in **classpath**). I am doing munit using java. Currently, these placeholders are not getting replaced by values in property file. Any idea how do I load this file while running munit?

My munit is like this:

```
Class MyClass extends FunctionalMunitSuite{

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {

        //try 1[gave give value pairs directly]: didnt worked
         System.getProperties().put("prop.key", "value");

         //try2[load prop files]:didn't worked
         prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("mypropertyfile.properties"));
         System.setProperties(prop); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Overriding `getConfigResources()` specify a `test-config.xml` which has your mock connector and context property placeholder of properties file. Store that test properties file in src/test/resources

```
@Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "mule-config-test.xml" + ",actual-flow-to-test.xml";
    }
```

Inside `mule-config-test.xml`, define test property file like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="wmo-mule-app.properties,wmo-mule-app-unit-test.properties" />
```

In this case, `wmo-mule-app.properties` is my actual app property file while `wmo-mule-app-unit-test.properties` is the over-riding unit-test property file. This unit-test property file will take precedence over `wmo-mule-app.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you might be having your files in **/src/main/resources**
try to put it in **/src/test/resources**